# Как отследить, какие скрипты выполняются сайтом и что они при этом записывают в БД/файлы?

Tags: php, cms

Добрый день! Есть локальный сервер OpenServer, есть CMS - не буду называть какая (одна из платных) - и мне нужно как-то отследить, какие php скрипты работают и что они записывают (что-то в БД или создают файлы или ещё что-то) в момент разворачивания дистрибутива CMS. Возможно как-то на локальном сервере включить какой-нибудь хитрый лог, который будет записывать каждое действие в процессе установки?

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно нормальную IDE и **xdebug**

Я использую [PHPStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/)
Тут как настроить: https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/configuring-xdebug.html